# How do I add a logo to my website?

Tags: wp-head, logo

I would like to know how to do add a logo to my [website](http://abraham-accountants.co.uk/), before the site title.

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<?php /* Embeds HTML5shiv to support HTML5 elements in older IE versions plus CSS Backgrounds */ ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<?php // Get Theme Options from Database
    $theme_options = smartline_theme_options();
?>

<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">

    <div id="header-wrap">

        <?php // Display Top Navigation
        if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary' ) ) : ?>

        <nav id="topnav" class="clearfix" role="navigation">
            <h5 id="topnav-icon"><?php _e('Menu', 'smartline-lite'); ?></h5>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(  array(
                'theme_location' => 'secondary', 
                'container' => false, 
                'menu_id' => 'topnav-menu', 
                'fallback_cb' => '', 
                'depth' => 1)
            );
            ?>
        </nav>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <header id="header" class="clearfix" role="banner">

            <div id="logo" class="clearfix">

                <?php do_action('smartline_site_title'); ?>

                <?php // Display Tagline on header if activated
                if ( isset($theme_options['header_tagline']) and $theme_options['header_tagline'] == true ) : ?>            
                <h2 class="site-description"><?php echo bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>

            <div id="header-content" class="clearfix">
                <?php get_template_part('inc/header-content'); ?>
            </div>

        </header>

    </div>

    <div id="navi-wrap">

        <nav id="mainnav" class="clearfix" role="navigation">
            <h4 id="mainnav-icon"><?php _e('Menu', 'smartline-lite'); ?></h4>
            <?php // Display Main Navigation
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary', 
                    'container' => false, 
                    'menu_id' => 'mainnav-menu', 
                    'echo' => true, 
                    'fallback_cb' => 'smartline_default_menu')
                );
            ?>
        </nav>

    </div>

    <?php // Display Custom Header Image
        smartline_display_custom_header(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The title is probably placed within the header.php file.

So openup and find something like:

```
<h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>"><?php bloginfo('name');?></a></h1>
```

This is what displays `Abraham & Co` on your website.

Now first of you need your image uploaded to you images folder in the theme folder.
Add the following code BEFORE the code above:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/your-logo.png">
```

make sure you change `your-logo.png` to whatever image file you have uploaded to you images folder.

Optionally you can wrap the image in a div with a class to add some css in your `style.css` file

-- UPDATE -- 
I have downloaded the theme that you use but indeed this isn't in the `header.php` file. There is a file called `template-tags.php`. 
In this file on rule 17 you find `<h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>`

This is what displays `Abraham & Co` on your website. But you should first check to add a logo via the admin screen options of you theme because I believe you can just upload an image.

If you can't do the following:
Upload your image to your images folder in your theme folder.
Replace:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
</a>
```

and replace it with:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/your-logo.png">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
</a>
```

Comment: I can't find no h1 code in my header php file.

Comment: In your original post please insert the content of your `header.php`

Comment: Thank you let me know Sir however i can upload image but it appear under header i want to be appear before site title on the left.

Comment: Then you can maybe just do this with some css

Comment: I have already uploaded images on to my theme folder                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/AA.png">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
</a>                                                            Is this right Sir before i copy and paste into php file

Comment: I hope so :-). Upload the file and see. Next time create a trial environment so you can try these things first. Keep in mind that if the theme gets an update you might loos the changes!!!!!!

Comment: Hello Sir it has worked thank you however how do i move to left side before site title if you have a look at website currently

Comment: I look at your website but I don't see the logo.... Never mind. Can you wrap them in a div with a class? change `<div class='my-logo'><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/AA.png"></div>`

Comment: If you have added the `<div class="my-logo">` add this to your style.css file: my-logo{display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: -33px 10px 0 -20px;};

Comment: Hello I have done that however it shows above the title line but it only appearing on the website once i am log-in as admin. but when i check in another web browser it don't appear. I am wondering if this need to be added in the code: backgroud:url(http://abraham-accountants.co.uk/wp-content/logo/AA.gif)

Comment: No it is because of your cache. Just do a hard refresh.

Comment: Ok I wondering where about do i need add css code into my style sheet.

Comment: I added css code it but it don't move to left and it still to appear in other web browser i'm i doing something wrong.

Comment: You have to add the `<div class='my-logo'>` before the `<img` and close with a `</div>`

Comment: This what I got in the php code:                           <div class='my-logo'><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/AA.gif"></div>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">

Comment: Yes I see. This is good but it seems you haven't changed the `style.css` file. You are on the right track but I have to go. Maybe I have some time tomorrow!

Comment: Hello just let you know it appear on the website however i would like to know how i add move on left before site title whenever you are free could tell me tomorrow thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Please use chat for extended discussion, comments aren't meant for it.

Comment: @Rarst Yes if I can find the link I need to do that. @Anees. I still don't see the `<div>` wrapping the `<img>` tag

Comment: That would be http://chat.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Thnx. But...... It needs a 20 points reputation. Anees doesn't have 20 points reputation!

Comment: @AneesYaquoob Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Smartline Lite: header.php file and change the below given code. let me know if it works ....

```
   <div id="logo" class="clearfix">

        <?php do_action('smartline_site_title'); ?>
<img src="image location" alt="alt title" height="auto" width="auto">

        <?php // Display Tagline on header if activated
        if ( isset($theme_options['header_tagline']) and $theme_options['header_tagline'] == true ) : ?>            
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php echo bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

    <div id="header-content" class="clearfix">
        <?php get_template_part('inc/header-content'); ?>
    </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Two Options, either define the url or link your defined custom logo from the theme settings.

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/menuLogo.png">
```

```
<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_custom_logo/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/

Comment: I think the problem here was knowing where to put that in the theme though.